# ActiveX Used in Lync communicator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, activex

Suppose I have an application where If I click on my name It should open my communicator.

For that I used `< sip:mymailid >` but this open communicator as wll as my outlook mail box, as I want to open only "lync" not mail box.  For making this type of application what `activeX` should I use(I know about Name control ActiveX) or which property of Name Control ActiveX to invoke communicator only.